# Spring boot 2 upgrade issue with actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Config:
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'

Getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService
```

There is no CounterService class in this release of spring-starter-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE??
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, CounterService is been removed in SpringBoot 2.0.

We faced the same issue and we used `MeterRegistry` from micrometer instead of `CounterService`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please refer migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#migrating-custom-countersgauges)