# Spring Boot 2.1.7 | Unable to start app due to ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics

Upgrading my project from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.1.7.

As per the migration guide, CounterService class is deprecated so used MeterRegistry from micrometer instead of CounterService.

But at application startup, getting below exception

```
2019-09-04 13:25:52.087 ERROR 17940 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/CounterService;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at com.project.AAA.main(AAApp.java:23) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/CounterService;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1097)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
... 12 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/CounterService;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.compiledByAjc(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.isAspect(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:104)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1097)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
... 33 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 45 common frames omitted
```

Usage of class

> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService

is removed from code.

Here is [dependency tree](https://github.com/ChetanSankhala/share/blob/master/dependncy-tree-attachement-for-question-57784042).

Below solution does not worked
[Spring boot 2 upgrade issue with actuator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52543242/3793554)

Comment: Please upload pom.xml (or any build file).

Comment: @MehrajMalik added dependency tree link in description

Comment: @BadDeveloper i am upgrading from 1.5.x to 2.x

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Please respond with the solution, if you've found it!